# Where does "npm install --save @types/jasmine" install the TypeScript declaration files?

Tags: typescript, npm

I ran `npm install --save @types/jasmine`, and now my `describe`/`it`/`expect` calls all compile. However, I can't find where the declarations are stored, and attempts to reference the Jasmine types in other declarations also fail.

`$ find node_modules -name jasmine.*
node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css
node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js`

...but no TypeScript declaration.

Comment: `node_modules/@types/jasmine` is what immediately comes to mind to me. Not sure if it's right, though.

Comment: `node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts`

Comment: Weird. Re-ran the install and now its there, as expected. Thanks, all.

Answer (score 1):

The comments are correct.  Jasmine's declaration file will be in `node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts`.  To reference it in a declaration file you can simply do:

```
/// <reference types="jasmine" />

declare function blah(): jasmine.CustomMatcher;
```

Comment: I did not know about the `types` attribute to `<reference>`.  Thanks!